# Example of nilpotent profinite group

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, topological-groups, profinite-groups, nilpotent-groups

Is there any example of a topologically finitely generated profinite group $G$ which is nilpotent as a group but has an infinite torsion-part?

The question is motivated by the fact that an algebraic finitely generated nilpotent group has a finite torsion-part and I known that such is also the case for any topologically finitely generated profinite group which is abelian. I'm just curious since it seems I cannot find anything online in one sense or in another.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why am I in a situation of trying to inform a user with nearly 4k in rep, that they need to review [How to ask a good question on Math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|130.1313).  Step up, please.

Comment: @amWhy I was in a hurry and it didn't cross my mind to explicitly write down the motivation, which, to me, seemed "obvious", sorry.